# Log File Backup and empty the file instead of deleting in linux

Tags: linux, file, backup, logfile

I have a log file which i need to take a backup,

Then empty the file instead of deleting it,

Deleting the file will cause someother script to get triggered,

Hence i should only empty it.

Please suggest me a way?

Answer (score 3):

After you've read from the file you can just overwrite the file with `> filename` This overwrites the file with nothing. It is also equivalent to `cat /dev/null > filename`.

similar solutions referenced [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92384/how-to-clean-log-file)

Comment: what if that log file is being used during my truncate operation, that will affect na?

Comment: If the file is open somewhere else it _should not_ adversely affect the operation of the other program. It is possible, but I highly doubt it, because you're just writing nothing to the file, so as long as the other program isn't expecting some data it should be fine. I'd test it out and if you have issues come back, update the post and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Acutually the file i am working with is a log file, my plan is to empty the file when it exceeds particular size, but backup it before emptying it,

Answer (score 0):

To empty a file you can use `truncate -s 0 filename`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no easy way to backup a file and empty it at the same time. I faced a similar problem and what I ended up doing is reading the original file line by line and copy them to a new file while keeping count of line numbers. Then I simply remove that number of lines from the original file. I use this to manually rotate some log files for which standard rotating approaches were not an option.

```
ORIGINAL_FILE="file.log"
NEW_FILE="$(date +%s).file.log"

unset n
while read line; do echo "$line" >> $NEW_FILE; : $((n++)); done < $ORIGINAL_FILE

if [[ -v n ]]; then
    sed -i "1,$n d" $ORIGINAL_FILE
fi
```